# Exclude a function from coverage

Tags: python, coverage.py, test-coverage

I am using [coverage.py](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.3/index.html) to get the test coverage of the code.

Suppose I have *two functions* with the same name in two different modules

```
# foo/foo.py

def get_something():
    # fetch something
    # 10 line of branch code
    return "something foo/foo.py"


# bar/foo.py

def get_something():
    # fetch something
    # 20 line of branch code
    return "something bar/foo.py"
```

How can I exclude the ***`bar.foo.get_something(...)`*** function "completely" ?

Comment: you could possible comment it out... this is only if you don't need to run the function aswell

Comment: Putting `# pragma: no cover` in all the lines is obviously not a good solution to the problem.

Comment: it was only a suggestion

Comment: use classes then each clan can have the same function names

Answer (score 33, accepted):

We can use ***`pragma`*** comment on the function definition level which tells the *coveragepy* to exclude the function completely.

```
# bar/foo.py

def get_something():  # pragma: no cover
    # fetch something
    # 20 line of branch code
    return "something bar/foo.py"
```

### Note

If we have the [coveragepy config file](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#configuration-reference) with an [**`exclude_lines`**](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/excluding.html#advanced-exclusion) setting in it, make sure that ***`pragma: no cover`*** in that setting because it overrides the default.

Comment: Note that this does _not_ work on code blocks in general, e.g. `if` or `with cm:` etc.

Comment: @Czechnology I don't think so, [see this](https://imgur.com/a/qr7X2Eo)

Comment: from the [doc](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/excluding.html#advanced-exclusion) *"The regexes only have to match part of a line. Be careful not to over-match. A value of `...` will match any line with more than three characters in it."*