# Can Pytest exclude certain lines of code?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm using Pytest to run test on one file that goes like this:

```
def function():...

def test_function():...

def main():...

main()
```

I want Pytest to exclude the line that calls main, is it possible?

Comment: `if __name__ == "__main__": main()`. And no, `pytest` can not skip code execution.

Comment: Yes, `pytest-cov` *can* exclude **considering** code as part of a coverage report. Disregarding comments and answers about **execution** of code, PyTest Coverage allows you to mark lines of code so they do not appear in the report: https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.5.0/excluding.html
See this answer which adds a little detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64628546/134044

Answer (score 0):

Pytest will execute only those functions with `test` as a prefix. Since you have already have a function `def function()` at the start there can be some issues running the entire test case.
As @hoefling commented, pytest can not skip the code.
Try adding the following at the end of you code:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```